# RedShift Copy - Unmatched Number of Columns - Possible to specify in Unload?

Tags: amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift

When trying to create a RedShift table from s3 data source, I'm running into the error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Spectrum Scan Error Details: -------------------------------------- 
--------- error: Spectrum Scan Error code: 15001 context: Unmatched number of columns between table and file. 
Table columns: 137, Data columns: 136, 
File name: https://s3.aws-region.amazonaws.com/s3_bucket/s3_data/part_date=2020-01-01/0044_part_00.parquet 
query: 10191102 location: dory_util.cpp:922 process: fetchtask_thread [pid=xxxxxx]
```

So the source table for this is a spectrum table created from data in s3 partitioned by date.  It's created using the UNLOAD command and then the AWS Glue crawler was used to create the spectrum table.  The crawler shows that there are 137 columns, but I'm thinking that not all of the parquet files are indicating that.  Is there a way to force the UNLOAD to propagate all 137 columns across the unloaded parquet files to avoid this error?

Here's my UNLOAD:

```
unload('select * from my table')
to 's3://path/to/data'
parquet
partition by (part_date)
allowoverwrite;
```

And here's how I was trying to copy (select as + truncate just to ensure schema):

```
drop table if exists db.table;
create table db.table
distkey (part_date)
sortkey (part_date, key_1, key_2)
as
select * from spectrum_table limit 1;
truncate db.table;

copy db.table
from 's3://path/to/data'
iam_role 'iam_role_details'
format as parquet;
```

Answer (score 0):

`select * from spectrum_table limit 1;` --Does this has the same number of columns that you expect from the s3 copy data file ? You have truncated the data but the structure remains intact.

If needed to specify the columns in the COPY command you can use this syntax - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html

```
COPY table-name 
[ column-list ]
FROM data_source
authorization
[ [ FORMAT ] [ AS ] data_format ] 
[ parameter [ argument ] [, ... ] ]
```

Comment: @david-buck I observed recently that the redshift copy command does not give error when the number of columns in the table don not match the number of columns in file.  Did redshift changed anything? Anyone ,  any idea?